# I have time series data in csv with both duplicate and missing time. Is this is possible to convert it to a xts object?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

My data looks something like this-

```
timestamp            value
2019-03-31 13:00:00  0
2019-03-31 14:00:00  1233
2019-03-31 14:00:00  1235
2019-03-31 15:00:00  1236
2019-03-31 17:00:00  NA
```

I would like to make an xts object out of it so that I can do some time-series analysis.

I tried this one-

```
try <- read.table("datafile.csv", sep = ",", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

But it gives me error like-

```
Error in read.table("datafile.csv", sep = ",", header = T, 
row.names = 1) : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed 
In addition: Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns
```

But anyway I tried to convert it to xts object with-

```
as.xts(try)
```

However, it gives me following error-

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I have tried some other things as well but nothing is working. I am quite new in R and xts object. Can you kindly help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question precisely what you have but assuming we have the file generated in the Note at the end:

```
library(xts)

DF <- read.csv("datafile.csv")
xts(DF[[2]], as.POSIXct(DF[[1]]))
```

giving:

```
                    [,1]
2019-03-31 13:00:00    0
2019-03-31 14:00:00 1233
2019-03-31 14:00:00 1235
2019-03-31 15:00:00 1236
2019-03-31 17:00:00   NA
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "timestamp,value
2019-03-31 13:00:00,0
2019-03-31 14:00:00,1233
2019-03-31 14:00:00,1235
2019-03-31 15:00:00,1236
2019-03-31 17:00:00,NA"
cat(Lines, file = "datafile.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works quite well. Really appreciate it. May I ask why are we using [[ ]] in this case? I haven't understood this part.

Comment: DF[[i]] is the ith column.  You can use DF$timestamp and DF$value if you prefer.